# Setting Date in google calendar event

Tags: java, date, datetime, google-calendar-api

I am trying to set start date of an event in google calendar but it keeps taking the wrong value. 
The code

```
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    Date dt = new Date(); 
    Date endDate = new Date(); 
     dt = df.parse("2015-05-23T09:00:00.000Z");
    endDate = df.parse("2015-05-25T09:30:00.000Z");

    start.setDateTime(new DateTime(dt));
    end.setDateTime(new DateTime(endDate));
```

But the variables 'end' and 'start' take the values "2014-12-28T09:30:00.000+05:30 " and "2014-12-28T09:00:00.000+05:30" respectively.
My Timezone is GMT+5:30 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because it should be:** `yyyy-MM-dd` not `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

here you can find what symbols int SimpleDateFormat means:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

and th big `DD` is day of the year, and the small `dd` is day of the month.